# Calling price function

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price

Trying to add Prices on my featured products and new products on Home Page.
The code for the new products is;

```
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List */
?>
<?php
  $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $catalog = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->setStoreId($storeId);

  $productList_block  = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list');       
    $_productCollection=$productList_block->getLoadedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', Varien_Data_Collection::SORT_ORDER_DESC);;
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <h3><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h3>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="mini-products-list home-mini-products-list" id="mini-products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                <?php /* Based on the native RWD styling, product images are displayed at a max of ~400px wide when viewed on a
                        one column page layout with four product columns from a 1280px viewport. For bandwidth reasons,
                        we are going to serve a 300px image, as it will look fine at 400px and most of the times, the image
                        will be displayed at a smaller size (eg, if two column are being used or viewport is smaller than 1280px).
                        This $_imgSize value could even be decreased further, based on the page layout
                        (one column, two column, three column) and number of product columns. */ ?>
                <?php $_imgSize = 150; ?>
                <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->keepFrame(false)->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
            </a>
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop home-product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>                     
                    </div>                   
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-shop-action">
              <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                  <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $catalog->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
                  <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
              <?php else: ?>
                  <?php
                    // Code for ETA Date, if the product if Out of Stock 
                    $eta_date = getProductETADate($_product); 
                    if($eta_date != "")
                    {
                  ?>
                    <span class='product-eta-date'>ETA: <?php echo $eta_date; ?></span>
                  <?php } else { ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>  
                  <?php } ?>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="clearBoth"></div>
        </li>
    <?php if($_iterator >= 10) break; endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('mini-products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?>
    <?php $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <ul class="products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php /*if ($i++%$_columnCount==0): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                    <?php $_imgSize = 210; ?>
                    <img id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"
                         src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($_imgSize); ?>"
                         alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                </a>
                <div class="product-info">
                    <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>                                        
                </div>
                <div class="desc std">
                        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped ?>" class="link-learn"><?php echo $this->__('Learn More') ?></a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <?php /*if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
            <?php endif*/ ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last'])</script>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

No matter what I add to try and get the

> ->getPrice()

function nothing shows up. Anything I am missing here?

I've setup a test site www.test.zyqor.com.au if you would like to view what I have done.

Here is my updated code;

```
            <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <div class="product-primary">
                        <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); ?>
                        <?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice() ?>
                        <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h2>                     
</div>
```

I added

```
<?php echo $_product->getFinalPrice() ?>
```

but still nothing showing up?

Comment: Have you tried `$product->getFinalPrice()`.

Comment: Ok I tried using
<?php echo $product->getFinalPrice() ?>
But nothing showing up

Comment: I think your `$product` is `$_product`

Comment: Hmm still not working. Should I be adding this under any particular bit. I've added it at the start and at the end with no difference.

Comment: You should add after your forloop. Meaning near your product name.

Comment: Still not working, I updated my question with my updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43716/discussion-between-adarsh-khatri-and-suranyi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$_product->getFinalPrice()` to get the final price of the product.

You should place this inside your foreach loop. After this line `<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>`

Also remember to add in both view- `grid and list`.

**And finally you should clear your cache each time you make any changes.**

Comment: Excellent answer. Thankyou